# custom email unable to send magento

Tags: error, email

I get the following error:
"exception 'exception' with message 'this letter cannot be sent.' magento" , in magento php.
below is the code i have used.

### Observer.php

```
<?php
class Metro_Purchaseorder_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{ 
    public function shipmentEmail($observer)
                {
                    $event = $observer->getEvent();
                    if(!$order = $event->getOrder())
                    {
                                    $order_Id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout()
                      ->getLastOrderId();
                                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_Id);
                                    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
                    }
                    $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethod();
                    $storeId = $order->getStoreId();
                    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_email_po_template');   
                    $emailTemplateVariables = array();                  
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = 'Branko';
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = 'Ajzele';
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = 'ActiveCodeline';
                    $emailTemplateVariables['storeid'] = $storeId;                  
                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    /*  $emailTemplate->setSenderName('MetroCC');
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('info@metrocc.com');
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($this->__('PO Test mail'));  */
                    //send mail
                    $emailTemplate->send('sachin301190@gmail.com', 'sachin', $emailTemplateVariables); 
                    return true;
                }       
}
```

in Config.xml

```
------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
        <Metro_Purchaseorder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Metro_Purchaseorder>
    </modules>
          <frontend>
            <events>
                <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                    <observers>
                        <purchaseorder_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Metro_Purchaseorder_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>shipmentEmail</method>
                        </purchaseorder_observer>
                    </observers>
                </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            </events>
            </frontend>
                <global>
                  <template>
                        <email>                     
                                <purchaseorder_custom_email1 translate="label" module="purchaseorder">
                                        <label>Purchaseorder module</label>
                                        <file>sales/purchaseorder_custom_email1.html</file>
                                        <type>html</type>
                                </purchaseorder_custom_email1>
                        </email>
                        </template>      
                  </global>    
</config>
```

Please help me in correcting the above error for sending custom email template

Answer (score 0):

Sachin,You issue with  event parameter.**checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** give last order ids in a  array .
You can easy check at class **[Mage_Checkout_OnepageController](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php)**  at function `successAction`.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
```

your observer code is

```
<?php
class Metro_Purchaseorder_Model_Observer {

    public function shipmentEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
        {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
            return;
        }
        foreach($orderIds as $eachOrderId){
             $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);
            try {
                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($eachOrderId);
                    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
                    $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
                    $storeId = $order->getStoreId();
                    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_email_po_template');   
                    $emailTemplateVariables = array();                  
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = 'Branko';
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = 'Ajzele';
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = 'ActiveCodeline';
                    $emailTemplateVariables['storeid'] = $storeId;                  
                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    /*  $emailTemplate->setSenderName('MetroCC');
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('info@metrocc.com');
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($this->__('PO Test mail'));  */
                    //send mail
                    $emailTemplate->send('sachin301190@gmail.com', 'sachin', $emailTemplateVariables); 
                    return true;


                }catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            }
        break;
        }
            return $this;
        }

}
```

Comment: Hi Amit thanks for your reply. I tried your code in Observer.php   I get :                                     Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethod() on boolean

Comment: Could you please suggest on what care has to be taken for the following error on line 17 in the above code for          Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethod() on boolean

Comment: check  again.............

Answer (score 0):

You commented out some important code:

```
/*  $emailTemplate->setSenderName('MetroCC');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('info@metrocc.com');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($this->__('PO Test mail'));  */
```

Emails can only be sent if the sender name, sender email and template subject are **all set**.